# Check List item end date synchronously

Tags: 2010, visual-studio

Hi I have one List with End date field.

I want to check synchronously that end date is greater then Today date or not and on that bases add update other list item.

How I done that operation.
Any Idea...

Answer (score 1):

piece of cake, create an item even receiver in the item updated event do what you need.

**http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122**

Comment: thanks for reply but i am not able to edit item or any thing with list item. so event receiver is not the way.
What you say about Timer Job.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should create a timer job for doing this, inside the timer job you can access Lists, its items and everything.. follow the link below:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-Custom-416cd3a1

To debug your timer job, attach the process to OWSTIMER service
or you can add System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() line of code where you need to debug!

I hope it helps!